# I install vim ext on vscode with macbookpro, but vim can't working, {hjkl} does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

### In my macbookpro, vscode vim ext does not work, {hjkl} does't move cursor

[vim ext install state img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njlQi.png); 
[vim {hjkl} does't move img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UFkl.gif);

I try this blog: https://wesleywiser.github.io/post/vscode-vim-repeat-osx/, does't not work too.

- mac osx: Catalina Versioin: 10.15.4
- vscode Version: 1.45.1

Comment: Are you in normal mode? try pressing esc before using hjkl for navigation.

Comment: I try  pressing esc , but does't be work.

Comment: Check if the extension is enabled.

Comment: Update vim extension and vscode to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I cannot use them at the same time......[Facepalm][Facepalm][Facepalm]
[latest version and enabled vim][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdrAD.png)